# Bash - how to use "and" and "and-and" at the same time? (& and &&)

Tags: linux, bash

In bash how do I chain commands using `&&` while also using a single ampersand `&` at the end of a command?

Something like:

```
my-program & && \
another-program-that-monitors-the-first $!
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: `&&` after `&` doesn't make sense because `&&` depends on exit value of the previous command and when a command is run in background using `&` then there is no exit value available

Comment: How do you expect it to work exactly? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @anubhava Right, maybe I could just use semi-colon then?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Run the second command after the first one has started in the background. I will update my question to show a clearer example.

Comment: Yes `my-command & my-next-command`

Comment: @anubhava Oh you don't even need a semi-colon in between?

Comment: No because `&` itself acts as a terminator

Comment: @anubhava Ok that makes sense. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @DavidCallanan. `&&` is a short circuiting operator. If you aren't relying on the first command ending before the second begins, it's not the right operator for you.

Comment: @DavidCallanan. You could also just put the commands on separate lines at that point

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes I understand now thanks. I don't think I can put it on separate lines because I am using a Makefile, and if I remember correctly each line is run in isolation.

Comment: @DavidCallanan Each *logical* line, not each *physical* line. Makefiles allow for line continuation to spread a single logical line across multiple physical lines.

Comment: @chepner But how do I tell make to leave the newline intact? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just call the second command right after the first `&`.

E.g:

```
my-program & \
another-program-that-monitors-the-first $!
```

Comment: Why the "\" ? It does nothing.

Comment: That "\" is basically to allow users to type commands in the `next line` of the shell. If you don't put "\" and type enter, the command will be executed right away.

Comment: Cool! Nice trick, if you want that (not execute command right away), and in an interactive shell (as in, used interactively) that makes sense. Well, in a script makes no difference.